# Why the hyperlink to the "URL : https://www.google.com/" is not working in W3Schools' "Try it Yourself" editor only?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, anchor, href

I am learning HTML from **The World's Largest Web Developer Site** w3schools.com

I am having an issue at this [URL](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links) from [HTML Links](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) chapter.

The Homepage of [World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)'s](https://www.w3.org/) website opens when I click on the hyperlink https://www.w3.org/ but same is not the case when I click on a hyperlink https://www.google.com/ to open [Google's](https://www.google.com/) homepage.

It's giving me error as **"www.google.com refused to connect."**

Why so?

This issue is coming when I tried to run the below code in **W3Schools' "Try it Yourself" editor**. When I tried to run the same below code from **localhost** in my web browser it worked perfectly fine and Google's homepage is opened.

Consider the code  tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <h2>Absolute URLs</h2>
    <p><a href="https://www.w3.org/">W3C</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

So my question is what's the issue with **W3Schools' "Try it Yourself" editor**?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem, Google just don't allow you to put them in an `iframe` (which is what w3schools use). If you right click and press 'open in new tab', it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the website and open the console, you can see what the error is. In this case the output is: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` Which means that google simply doesn't allow to display google.com on an iframe, which is what is being used by w3schools.